# Creating a new Commit from changes made in a previous commit

Tags: git

I was working on an app and when I pulled new code today morning, I found that the app was not working, so, I did a `git checkout` to go to a previous commit.

Now I have made some changes to this commit and I want to create a new commit with these changes.

Is this possible? If not, please suggest a way to achieve the objective.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have made some changes to this commit"? Did you commit any changes after `git checkout`? Or did you only edit the local copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have previously done `git checkout abcdef` and made changes; now you do:

```
git checkout -b foo
```

which will not make any changes to source files, it just creates a new branch name `foo`.

Then you do the usual `git add` and `git commit` commands that you would do to commit changes.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your branch is master

```
git checkout f95ecfe // previous commit
git checkout -b bug_fix // Create branch at current possition
git add -A //make change and add
git commit -m 'commit message'
git checkout master 
git merge bug_fix
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Okay. But I have already made changes to the previous commit (quoting your example: `f95ecfe`). 
Will this method still work?

Comment: have you commited the changes?

Comment: No. not yet. I have to in 15 min or so.

Comment: ok no problem follow the same steps. first checkout to new branch from the commit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very possible.

```
git checkout branch_Id // previous commit
git checkout -b new branch name // Create branch at current position
git add .//make change and add

git commit -m 'your commit statement'

git checkout master 

git merge new branch name
```

Comment: You’ll still need to create a pointer to the commit. Otherwise it’s unreachable without the sha ref.

Comment: I don't think this will work. How will `git` know that we need the commit to be the latest one? and what about the files which might have changed due to other people's commits  after the commit in which I am currently working on?

Comment: @ArjunPanicker you end up with two branches which split apart at the place you checked out to.  One branch has your change and the other branch has the changes made by the other people.  If this is not your objective then I would suggest editing your question to explain what you mean by "the objective".

Answer (score 1):

Just `git checkout master; git commit`.  Changes in your index and worktree stay there until you commit them.  If there are conflicting changes between your work and the new checkout, `git checkout -m master` and resolve the conflicts, then `git commit`.